# How do I start receiving emails again?

Tags: iphone, icloud, email

I got a notification that my iCloud subscription has ended and that my storage is full. I paid for my storage on that day and I need my emails but ever since I paid for my storage I still haven’t received any emails for 2 days and I am freaking out because it’s important.

I looked everywhere for an answer. Turning off my phone and restarting it but nothing.

Comment: Is the iCloud your primary email server ? is it it gmail or ?

Comment: Something like this that involves service suspension/reactivation is usually something the vendor (Apple) is in the best position to deal with.  There’s no hidden setting on your device that address this issue

Comment: I don’t have a suspension or anything it wasn’t like this before. I did nothing wrong all I did was pay for my iCloud and yet emails stopped coming through. I restarted my phone I deleted the app and downloaded it again but nothing

Comment: You stated that the subscription ended.  The service will get suspended until a payment method is updated.

Comment: Email that was sent while the account was undeliverable most likely were returned with a bounce.  They don't queue forever.

Comment: Allan I paid for my subscription again so I wouldn’t be suspended